# Sort MySQL select from another table data

Tags: mysql, sorting

First of all I searched for this topic and I found some same topic threads, But i don't understand how to apply it to my scenario :/

I have 2 tables that involve this query.

```
Table : Discussions            Table : Comments
--------------------           -------------------------------------
|id | content      |           | id | d_id | content   | timestamp |
--------------------           -------------------------------------
| 1 | Text String  |           | 1  |  2   | Comment 1 | timestamp |
| 2 | Text String  |           | 2  |  3   | Comment 2 | timestamp |
| 3 | Text String  |           | 3  |  4   | Comment 3 | timestamp |
| 4 | Text String  |           | 4  |  2   | Comment 4 | timestamp |
| 5 | Text String  |           | 5  |  3   | Comment 5 | timestamp |
--------------------           -------------------------------------
```

Now I need to get the id from discussion table & need to sort it using *d_id* in the comment table according to Unix timestamp.

So discussion with recent comment will list first in the website.

Hope you got the idea. Please tell me how to write SQL query for this.

Comment: You should also show us your expected output.  This looks like you should be joining the two tables on `Discussions.id = Comments.d_id`, but then it isn't clear how or what you want to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple join will fetch each discussion multiple times (as the number of comments the discussions has).
This query will return each discussion at most once:

```
SELECT d_id FROM Comments GROUP BY d_id ORDER BY MIN(timestamp) DESC
```

Of course, if you want more data, not just `Discussions.id`, you'll have to do some joins.

Note also that this query doesn't return discussions ids that don't have any comments. For that too you'll have to join.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question well, then you need to join the two tables

```
select Comments.d_id, Discussions.content as d_content, Comments.content as c_content
from Comments
join Discussions
on Discussions.id = Comments.d_id
order by Discussions.id, Comments.timestamp
```

EDIT:

```
select Comments.d_id, Discussions.content as d_content, Comments.content as c_content
from Comments
right join Discussions
on Discussions.id = Comments.d_id
order by Discussions.id, Comments.timestamp
```

Comment: with this what happens if there is no comment associated with recently posted discussion ?

Comment: @ShyaminAyesh it will not be among the results. You might want to use right join if you still want to see these records among the results.

Comment: how to use right join please ? I previously tried with left join but it didn't work ? can you post query of left join ?